# How do I find a partition of an equivalence relation?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations

Say I have the function:
$$x\,R\,y \iff y = 3^k$$ for some $k \in \mathbb Z$ and the set is:

$$A = \{1,1/3,1/27,1/4,3,1/36 , 2,2/9,9/4, 5\}$$

So in this scenario, how do I find the partitions of the set?

Knowing a fairly example should allow me to know how to do it in the future.

Answer (score 1):

An equivalence relation is always partition. In general you want to put it in the form of a set. Here, you can say,

$$A_{r}= \{(x,y) | y = \frac{x}{3^k}\}$$

Where $A_r$ denotes the equivalent partition corresponding to your relation. Also, $k$ is assumed to be an integer.

Comment: A partition is a set of disjoint subsets that covers a set. A relation is a set of ordered pairs. Your $A_r$ is not a partition.

Comment: It is implied that the other class is the set of numbers which do not satisfy this relation. In that case, we do have a partition.

Comment: Wrong. All you did in your answer was rewrite the relation as a set of ordered pairs. What you need to do is define each set of $R$ related elements of $A$.

Comment: Well, using the definition of a partition, you can clearly see this is a partition. I am not sure what you are having trouble with.

Comment: How can an ordered pair be a member of a partition of $A$?

Comment: This is a class of a partition. Not the partition itself. The other class is the set of pairs NOT satisfying this. This is assumed. The indexed family of these sets is the partition. I am sorry you are having trouble.

Comment: Perhaps you should edit your answer to include your definitions instead of being sorry when people don't understand what you are saying.

Answer (score -1):

A partition of a set $A$ is a collection of $a_i \subset A$ such that each  $a_i$ is disjoint from the others and $\bigcup a_i = A$.

An equivalence relation always partitions a set. Given a set $A$ and some relation $R$, the set of equivalence classes $A/R$ is a partition of $A$. Each member of $A/R$ is a subset of $A$ such that each member is $R$ related.

Since your given set is a finite set, perhaps the simplest approach would be to start with an element and determine all the other elements that are $R$ related to it. The set of all these elements is one equivalence class in the partition. Then pick another element from $A$ that is not in this first equivalence class, and form another class. Once all the elements of $A$ have been grouped, you will have formed the partition of $A$ that you are looking for.